Databricks logging for a wheel task
I'm trying to run a Databricks wheel task and print some logs. I created a logging utility:
# log_utils.py
import sys
import logging
from typing import Optional

def setup_logging(
    name: Optional[str] = None, level: Optional[int] = None
) -> logging.Logger:

    if level is None:
        level = logging.INFO

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    # change py4j logging level to warning
    logging.getLogger("py4j.clientserver").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(level)

    fmt = "%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
    datefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

This utility is called in an entry-point:
# __init__.py

import logging
from log_utils import setup_logging

def entrypoint():

    logger = setup_logging(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger.info("Logging an operation")

This package is uploaded as a wheel, and run in a task. I would expect, when I run my job, to see in the output of the task the line "Logging an operation". Instead, I see nothing printed.
How do I see these logs in the Output section of a Databricks Job?
As a reference, I ran the following code:
# __init__.py

import logging
from log_utils import setup_logging

def entrypoint():

    logger = setup_logging(level=logging.DEBUG)

    logging.info("logging.info - foo")
    logger.info("logger.info - bar")
    print("print - baz")

What I'd like to see is
# OUTPUT
logging.info - foo
logger.info - bar
print - baz

while what I see is
# OUTPUT
print - baz

